# AWS 'The instance is running on degraded hardware.' And about my software

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using AWS EC2 instance now. 
I got the message "The instance is running on degraded hardware".
I found what I should do. 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=105610

I read a reason 
"This means that your instance that is virtually running on a physical host which is having hardware problems so it is not running optimally and this could cause your instance to become inaccessible."

"all you have to do is just start it again and it will then spawn on a new healthy host."

My EC2 instance hardware has a NVME and my mongodb data in it.

I wonder if I stop and start my EC2 instance, and my EC2's hardware will be changed, And my mongodb data will be disappeared? or still in it?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Is your mongodb persistent (backed by disk) or just stored in memory? If just in memory, you will loose the contents.

Comment: NVMe is attached instance storage, and therefore disappears when the instance is stopped [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ssd-instance-store.html#nvme-ssd-volumes). You should spin up a new instance and copy your data (and you should be taking regular backups as well!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test this easily: spin up a small instance, write a file.  Restart the instance, log in again.  File still there with the contents?  There’s your answer.

If you have data you wish to keep a good test beats relying on the internet for answers, even if it is stack overflow;)

Comment: There's no need to test this.  Ephemeral disks will not survive a stop/start, by design, and NVMe disks in EC2 instances are always ephemeral.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

Comment: Sure. Nothing beats actual experience though. Giving a fish vs teaching to fish and all.